# Copy rows based on column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` that can have 6 different inputs in column types: 3 inputs being `string`, `word` and `something` and the other 3 inputs its name with an `s` in the end :

```
         types     Value    File   Number
0       string       Old     dat      1.0   
1         word       Old     dat      2.0
2    something       Old     dat      3.0
3   somethings       Old     dat      4.0
4        words       Old     dat      5.0
```

And I want to get a  `df` in which I replicate only the rows that don't have a corresponding `s` in the end in column types. And add a `str(New)` to column Value.

Output:

```
         types    Value    File   Number
0       string      Old     dat      1.0
1         word      Old     dat      2.0
2    something      Old     dat      3.0        
3   somethings      Old     dat      4.0
4        words      Old     dat      5.0
5       string      New     dat      1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
def insert_rows(df):
    types = df["types"].values
    unique_without_s = [t for t in types if t[-1] != 's']
    unique_with_s = [w for w in unique_without_s if f"{w}s" in types]
    diff = [w for w in unique_without_s if w not in unique_with_s]
    new_df = df.copy()
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.types in diff:
            new_df = new_df.append({"types": row['types'], "Value": 'New', 
                           "File": row['File'], "Number": row['Number']}, ignore_index=True)
    return new_df
```

Comment: Thanks, but correct me if I'm wrong; this code is searching for the types that don't end with an 's'. My aim is to insert only the ones that don't have a respective `s`
In example you can see that I only add the `string` because it is the only one which don't have a respective `s` in the end

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. I got confused because of the addition of a new value though: so you want to keep only the rows where the `type` does not end with an s. But when do you want to have the Value `New` inserted then?

Comment: In your example output, `word`, first `string` and `something` also do not have an `s`, but do not get a `New` value :)

Comment: Sorry,  maybe I was not clear. What I want is to see what words don't have a corresponding `s`. `word` and `something` have also (in the same column) `words` and `somethings`. So my aim in this example is only to add a new `string` because it is the only one that don't have a correponding `strings`

Comment: Ahh, I understand you now, let me edit my answer then!

Comment: Sorry, it does not work for the entire dataframe... for example the new elements of the other columns (File column)  get `NaN`, it should be a replica of the old one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216740/discussion-between-mabergerx-and-eduardo2111).